# fields.E304 Reverse accessor clashes in Django for multiple custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
ERRORS:
core.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'core.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'seller.User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'core.User.groups' or 'seller.User.groups'.
core.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'core.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'seller.User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'core.User.user_permissions' or 'seller.User.user_permissions'.
seller.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'seller.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'core.User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'seller.User.groups' or 'core.User.groups'.
seller.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'seller.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'core.User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'seller.User.user_permissions' or 'core.User.user_permissions'.
```

This is the error I get when I try to migrate two identical custom User Models. I copy pasted the code of the custom user model from my user app models.py to the seller app models.py.

```
# seller/models.py

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

```
# user/models.py

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

I tried renaming the custom user model but that didn't work, I have added separate `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py for both of them. I am also clueless where to add the `related_name`  to. Thank You, also be patient with me as I have started django 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Please *don't* define two user models. This will only generate (a lot of) trouble. Define *one* user model that you use for the rest of your project.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem eeks, sorry... So, should I import the User model from the user app's models.py to the seller app's models.py and change the fields in the seller models.py. Will that work, if not what is the best practice?

Comment: keep one of the two `User` models. Probably better in the `core` app. You can then make `ForeignKey`s/`OneToOneField`s/`ManyToManyField`s that refer to that model by using `ForeignKey('core.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, so with a *string* literal.

Answer (score 1):

you need to mention `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your project `settings.py`